# Why does my phone use Google Public DNS?

Tags: cyanogenmod, networking, dns

I was just curious to know what DNS server my phone used. So I launched a terminal emulator and I entered:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

As you can see, my phone uses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers ([Google Public DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)).

At home (Wifi), my router is configured to give OpenDNS' servers through DHCP. But, on my phone, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` returns the same output. Same thing with 3G. And, even if I disable both Wifi and 3G, and then reboot the phone, it still uses Google's Public DNS servers.

I don't remember having changed `resolv.conf` or installed any application to change it.

My phone is an HTC Desire with CyanogenMod 7.2.0.1 (Android 2.3.7).

Can someone explain me why my phone uses Google Public DNS? Is it a common configuration for any Android devices, or CyanogenMod ROM?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to Steve Kondik](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=3818#c9), this is essentially old code that is leftover from older versions of CyanogenMod:

> This was only here for apps that were statically linked against uclibc in old CM versions. It can likely just be removed.

However, [he also goes on to note](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=3818#c10):

> Also, this file is NOT written when connecting to a network as /system is readonly. The actual DNS servers are read from system properties.
>
> I also just verified that the DHCP supplied servers are actually being used, so this issue is invalid unless someone proves otherwise.

So the values in `/etc/resolv.conf` actually don't reflect your DNS settings. What you can do instead is use `getprop` to find your DNS values. You can pare it down rather nicely if you grep the output like so:

```
getprop | grep dns
```

Also worth noting: the `/etc/resolv.conf` file appears to have been removed completely in later versions of CyanogenMod. I don't have one on CM10 at all, but `getprop` does correctly show my DNS settings.

Comment: Great answser, thanks. However, `getprop | grep dns` doesn't return anything. `getprop | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'` (looking for IPv4 address) doesn't return relevant result. Returned properties are `ro.baseband`, `ro.build.description`, `ro.modversion` and `gsm.version.baseband`. Any idea?

Comment: @Morgan: I suppose it might be some kind of difference between CM7 (you're running) and CM10 (what I tested on). What happens if you don't grep the output at all? Do you see anything relevant? (might want to pipe it into `more` or similar since it could be lengthy)

Comment: Now, I have relevant results: `[dhcp.eth0.dns1]: []`, `[dhcp.eth0.dns2]: []`, `[dhcp.eth0.dns3]: []`, `[dhcp.eth0.dns4]: []`, `[net.dns1]: [192.168.10.110]`, `[net.dns2]: []`, `[net.rmnet0.dns1]: [192.168.10.110]`, `[net.rmnet0.dns2]: [0.0.0.0]` , `[net.dns1.3837]: []`. Maybe my Internet connection was still disabled when I ran the command. Do you know which one is used? Do you recommend an application or a method to change it?

Comment: @Morgan: I don't have a Gingerbread device onhand to test, but there should be a way to do it in the standard wireless settings if you configure a static IP (I don't think you can do it this way if you use DHCP, unfortunately). On JB I long-press the network I'm connected to and select "Modify" to get to it. It may be under the "Advanced setttings" though (menu button when on the list of wifi networks). You can also use `setprop` but it won't persist across reboots/disconnects. For example. `setprop net.rmnet0.dns1 <your DNS IP>` should change the value of the `net.rmnet0.dns1` property.

Comment: And I *think* the more specific one would be used by the adapter (`net.rmnet0.dns1` in your case), though it may be inheriting that value from the more generic `net.dns1` property.

Comment: How can I make it so I dont have to specify a DNS in the static IP settings? Google forces me to use theirs but I need to use none.

Comment: @Rhyuk: I don't know. `setprop` might be a temporary solution if you gave it blank values, but you'd have to run it on every boot (and I'm not sure if that would actually work).

Comment: I tried that but setprop requires a value, blank wont work :(